# black screen in Android emulator in Ubuntu VM in Windows 7

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64, android-source

I built AOSP 5.1.0_r5 (LMY47O) with no modifications done to the source code. The build process ends with "success" and I get bunch of *.img files in [out/target/product/deb](http://pastebin.com/7pAZc876). Sadly, executing *emulator -verbose* produces the generic emulator window with an empty screen and following [output in the console](http://pastebin.com/LPRs7B6Q). I see nothing that would explain the black screen. (I am looking at the black screen for tens of minutes, hence I doubt it is "merely very slow.")

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 running in VirtualBox under Windows 7, no IDE involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an assumption. You have a line in your output: `Failed to create Context 0x3005
Could not initialize emulated framebufferemulator: Can't start OpenGLES renderer?` It seems that this is the cause of the problem. Could you please install the following libraries `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils-extra` and run your emualator once again?

P.S. What is the target `deb`? Try to build the AOSP using a recommended target, e.g., `aosp_arm-eng`.

Comment: "deb" is Nexus 7, my understanding is that is what I need to build when aiming to push the result to Nexus 7

Comment: as for the error, i assumed "using software renderer" means "you will see stuff, graphics will merely be slow as hell", but yes, i will try that, thank you :) I am currently starting all over (deleted and syncing repo again, not reinstalling the machine)

Comment: tested few of those "arm" targets, they seem to work with the emulator just fine... i assume that's because it is an emulator-aimed target, and for "deb" (and other device-specific targets) i would neet to build also the kernel?... i wish it was mentioned in the frikkin official guide in "Preparing to Build", could have saved me two weeks of wasted time :D

Comment: If you face with a problem, try to search the Internet. Most probably some of people have already faced with that. Their explorations may lead you to the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks but after 2 weeks of doing exactly that I realized it was about time I asked myself. :)